# Get error compiling example of gtk example from https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/

Tags: c, gtk3, msys2

Hi i am trying to compile the Hello World of gtk from the official website. I done everything asked and I installed GTK by msys2 package manager. My cmd cant detect the package-config directory. I have done setting path for my msys264 on the environment variable. I am sorry if it sounded confusing as I am begineer. TQ.

```
C:\Users\60182\Desktop\vc>gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the problem. Windows shell does not work like linux shells. The backtick character is used for passing the output of one command as a parameter to another.

So in order to do this manually, you can do something like this. First run the command `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` and then `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`. I don't know what the output will be, but assume the outputs are just "foo" and "bar" and that it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\60182\Desktop\vc>pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
foo

C:\Users\60182\Desktop\vc>pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
bar
```

Then you do this:

```
C:\Users\60182\Desktop\vc>gcc foo -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c bar
```

Comment: Hi there i tried  your suggestion but i got this gcc: error: foo: No such file or directory
gcc: error: bar: No such file or directory

Comment: @user13626458 You got what output?

Comment: And you should run `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` and not `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 foo`. In my example `foo` is the output.

Comment: Hi there i tried I got no error but I dont get any output.

Comment: Then just run `gcc -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c`

Comment: I got this instead hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: Sound like you need to check your include paths.

Comment: Hi there tq very much the problem is I am not running the exe file i just compile the code. TQ very much now I am very happy as I tried to find the solution for days. hahah tq so much have a nice day

Comment: Are you sure you installed the packages? When I call `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`, I see a long output.